# calculate quarters from months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  data frame with a number of columns by month

```
c1 c2 yyyy-01 yyyy-02 yyyy-03 yyyy-04 yyyy-05 yyyy-06 ...
 a  A     1      1       3      2       2        3     
 b  B     2      3       4      4       2        1
```

...
There are about 15 years of data 
I need to transform it to quarters
ie

```
c1 c2 yyyy-q1 yyyy-q2 ...
 a  A    5      7
 b  B    9      7 
...
```

and so forth. 
Any help?  It seems a map might do it, but I am not well versed in map or lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `pd.to_datetime()` and `to_period()` functions to create a group variable of quarters for each year;
2. You can pass an axis parameter to the `groupby()` function to group your data frame by columns, in this case the column index.

so, you can try:

```
df.set_index(['c1', 'c2'], inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period("Q"), axis=1).sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: I was thrashing about.  I thought I could use `pd.TimeGrouper` on a `PeriodIndex`.  I found out that I cannot.

Comment: It works for the quarters, but the reset_index is causing an error: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: SIZERANK

Comment: What pandas version are you using? It works for me on 0.19.x. You could try to upgrade your pandas or try to rename your columns as string before resetting index. Without a reproducible example, it's hard to know what is happening.

Comment: 0.18.1, with no way to upgrade. Renameing as str didn't help either.